# mysqli data insert working just fine but no data inserted into the database

Tags: php, html

I'm quite new to php although i understand the foundation of php. Most of it atleast.

there are 2 problems with my php script.

One: 
Even though i typed-in the information inside the text box it always directs me to the ?insert=empty im not sure why it's always telling me that one of the boxes are empty even though it isn't. is it the input type="date"?.

Two:
I tried removing the if(empty) method leaving the mysqli query. And it works just fine although no data was inserted into the database.

PHP

```
session_start();



if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

include 'includes/dbh.inc.php';
$id = $_GET['id'];
$c_id = $_REQUEST['u_uid'];
$e_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['e_name']) ;
$d_event = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['d_event']) ;
$t_event = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['t_event']) ;
$e_t_event = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['e_t_event']) ;
$theme = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['theme']) ;
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


    if (empty($e_name) || empty($d_event) || empty($t_event) || empty($e_t_event) || empty($theme)){

        header("Location: ../package.all.php?insert=empty");
        exit();
    }else{




$sql = "INSERT INTO event_table (event_name, event_date, event_time_start, event_time_end, cusact_id, theme, reserve_date_time, package_id) VALUES ('$e_name', '$d_event', '$t_event', '$e_t_event', '$theme', '$date', '$id');";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

header("Location: ../package.all.php?insert=success");

}
}
 else {

    echo 'isset was false'; 
    header("Location: ../inquire-packages.inc.php?insert=failed");

}
```

HTML

```
<form action="includes/inquire-packages.inc.php" method="POST">
<label>Event Name</label>
<input type="text" name="e_name" placeholder="Enter Event Name*"/>

<label for="job">Day of the Event</label>
<input type="date" name="d_event" placeholder="Enter Date of Event*"/>


<label for="job">Time of the Event</label>
<input type="Time" name="t_event" placeholder="Enter Time of Event*"/>

<label for="job">End Time of the Event</label>
<input type="Time" name="e_t_event" placeholder="Enter End Time of Event*"/>

<label>Theme</label>
<input type="text" name="theme" placeholder="Enter Theme*"/>
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but i really want to learn php code.

Thank you,
Omar

Comment: Your `$id` isnt set when you submit the form, but you use it in the query. Neither is `$c_id` seems like.

Answer (score 4):

**1st :** Column `count` doesn't match with `value` `count` . your column count is `8` but value count `7` . so you missed one value . try to debug it .

**2nd :** I guess you missed `$c_id`.

**3rd :** Try to use prepared statement to avoid sql injection .

**4th :** `Header()` function doesn't terminate the code execution . so use `exit()` after header function .

**5th :** Add error handler `mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));`

**6th :** And where from you get these two values `$id = $_GET['id'];$c_id = $_REQUEST['u_uid'];`

**PHP :**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO event_table (event_name, 
                                 event_date, 
                                 event_time_start, 
                                 event_time_end, 
                                 cusact_id, 
                                 theme, 
                                 reserve_date_time, 
                                 package_id) 
                        VALUES ('$e_name', 
                                '$d_event', 
                                '$t_event', 
                                '$e_t_event', 
                                '$c_id',
                                '$theme', 
                                '$date', 
                                '$id');";

  mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: Wow .. Excellent Explanation.

Comment: Thanks Man :) @MittulAtTechnoBrave

Comment: @JYoThI
Thanks :D It has already been inserted. But I can't seem to get my $_Session['u_uid'] it's always '0' even though im currently logged in to id number '5'.
event_tables:
http://prntscr.com/g869nj
Accounts:
https://prnt.sc/g869wd
This is where i get my $c_id = $_REQUEST['u_uid']
I want to pass that information form by form.

     //Log in the user here
     $_SESSION['u_contact']  = $row['cus_contact'];
     $_SESSION['u_email']  = $row['cus_email'];
     $_SESSION['u_uid']  = $row['cus_user'];
     header("Location:../index.php?login=success");

Comment: where your setting session ?

Comment: @OmarMandeeli I guess you are coming up with some new requirements in this. Please post as new question so that we can help you in that thread. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.real-escape-string.php#58650) of `mysqli_real_escape_string`, I found that if the connection is not open, the output will be an empty string, so try to check if the connection is open:

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("%s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```